# Android prepare videoRecorder stops preview

Tags: android, video, camera, recording

so I have a camera app that I also want to record videos.
when I push a button to switch from camera to video i do this

```
public void prepareVideoRecorder() {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.prepareRecorder(video_orientation, camera_surface);
    // mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

and my prepare method

```
public void prepareRecorder(int video_degrees, CameraSurfaceView sf) {
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();
    recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(sf.getHolder().getSurface());

    Log.v("this", "orientation hint = " + video_degrees);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOrientationHint(video_degrees);

    File imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM");
    String filename = imageFileFolder.toString() + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".mp4";
    recorder.setOutputFile(filename);

    recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

when i push the "switch" button the preview stops. But if i push the start recording button, everything works good, i can record the video and also the preview starts again.
 If i try to uncomment the mCamera.startPreview() from prepareVideoRecorder i get this error

```
    02-24 13:44:49.146: E/InputEventReceiver(18078): Exception dispatching input event.
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at org.dtaz.yoda.DtazCamera.startPreview(DtazCamera.java:136)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at org.dtaz.yoda.DtazPreview.prepareVideoRecorder(DtazPreview.java:343)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at org.dtaz.yoda.CameraActivity.swipeGesture(CameraActivity.java:600)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at org.dtaz.yoda.CameraSurfaceView.onTouchEvent(CameraSurfaceView.java:87)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2281)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
02-24 13:44:49.146: E/MessageQueue-JNI(18078):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.156: D/AndroidRuntime(18078): Shutting down VM
02-24 13:44:49.156: W/dalvikvm(18078): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41841c08)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078): Process: org.dtaz.yoda, PID: 18078
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at org.dtaz.yoda.DtazCamera.startPreview(DtazCamera.java:136)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at org.dtaz.yoda.DtazPreview.prepareVideoRecorder(DtazPreview.java:343)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at org.dtaz.yoda.CameraActivity.swipeGesture(CameraActivity.java:600)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at org.dtaz.yoda.CameraSurfaceView.onTouchEvent(CameraSurfaceView.java:87)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2333)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2281)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
02-24 13:44:49.166: E/AndroidRuntime(18078):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

anyone know what is going on?

Comment: can You provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I added it all!

Comment: ok, what is in line 136 and 343 in Your DtazCamera class?

Comment: 136 -> mCamera.startPreview(); the actual call on start preview on the camera object not my implementation. the 343 on Preview is also a call to my customcamera object. 

I have created a custom camera controler, with custom view, and custom callback that's why there are so many calls

Comment: sorry, I mean line 343 in Your DtazPreview class...

Comment: and can You please post also the part of the code where You start preview? Can´t see it here....

Comment: the mCamera.startPreview() calls the startPreview of my camera controller. It's ust the camera.startPreview() method, nothing else

Comment: ok, one possible issue could be that You are using the camera before for recording something. Try somehting: instead of using camera.unlock() in Your prepareVideoRecorder () method, call camera.reconnect(). ...

Comment: ok so If i add camera.reconect() in the end of my prepare method , the preview works find but when i hit start i got E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19  ..... :/

Comment: a devils circle...:) ...I think You should post the part where You start it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I came up with a solution, i don't know if it is the right one but it works.

The case is that in order to record video the camera instance needs to be acquired by the MediaRecorder and simultaneously if you want to show preview , the camera instance needs to be in the surfaceview. That's why if you start the recording you can see the image been captured.

so the only way to overcome this is to put the prepare inside the onclick method just before the mediarecorder.start() like this.

```
take_picture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isVideo) {
                if (!isRecording) {
                    camera_preview.prepareVideoRecorder();
                    camera_preview.startRecording();
                    take_picture.setText("stop");
                    isRecording = true;
                } else {
                    camera_preview.stopRecording();
                    take_picture.setText("start");
                    isRecording = false;
                }
            } 
        }
    });
```

If you put the code like this, everything works good. If anyone has a better solution please post it so we can use it!!!